# EF Core Many to Many relationship removal with entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Hello im so dumb that i can't find any way to make this delete.
I want to delete my "Contractor" by his ID with all OrderDatas, but the "Contractor" have additional "OrderData"
One:Contractor Many:OrderData, this "OrderData" also have another complication, there we god the additional "Magazyn", which is Many:OrderData Many: Magazyn.

The delete will also delete all Contractor OrderData's.
But im stucked at error 500 update or delete on table "OrderData" violates foreign key constraint "FK_ProductClass_OrderData_OrderDataOrderId" on table "ProductClass".

This is everything what i got and im beg for help, im just trying to learn the ASP... Bruh.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<OrderData>()
                .HasKey(bc => bc.OrderId);
            builder.Entity<OrderData>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.ContractorData)
                .WithMany(bc => bc.OrderData)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ContractorId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<Magazyn>()
                .HasMany(b => b.OrderData)
                .WithMany(bc => bc.Magazyn)
                .UsingEntity<OrderItems>(
                x => x.HasOne(x => x.OrderData).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),
                x => x.HasOne(x => x.Magazyn).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade));
        }
```

```
    public class OrderData
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderGUID { get; set; }
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Magazyn> Magazyn { get; set; }
        public int ContractorId { get; set; }
        public List<ProductClass>? ProductId { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public ContractorData ContractorData { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public string CreatorUsername { get; set; }
        public string OrderVendor { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Magazyn
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductGUID { get; set; }
        public int ProductSKU { get; set; }
        public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
        public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; } 
        public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
        public int ProductVatRate { get; set; }
        public double ProductNettoPurchasePrice { get; set; }
        public double ProductNettoSellingPrice { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int ProductDiscount {get; set; }
        public string ProductVolume { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public ICollection<OrderData> OrderData { get; set; }
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }

    }
```

```
    public class ProductClass
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid pcID { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class OrderItems
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public OrderData OrderData { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductsQuantity { get; set; }
        public Magazyn Magazyn { get; set; }
    }
```

And im done with this:

```
                public async Task<string> DeleteContractorAsync(int ContractorId)
        {
           var _contractor = await _context.ContractorData.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ContractorId == ContractorId);
            //var _subdata = await _context.OrderItems.Where(m => m.ContractorId).ToListAsync();
            var _orders = await _context.OrderData.Where(m => m.ContractorId == ContractorId).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var order in _orders)
            {
                var _orderItems = await _context.OrderItems.Where(m => m.OrderId == order.OrderId).ToListAsync();
                foreach(var item in _orderItems)
                {
                   _context.OrderItems.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            _context.ContractorData.Remove(_contractor);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return "123";
        }
```

Before i done with this i try a lot of examples, like delete first orderitems, then orderdata then contractor but anything just doesn't work well for me.
Before i add the

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

in the builder im getting same 500 error but on FKOrderData

Answer (score 1):

Ok i made it.
I just add another Column to the "ProductClass", the column name "Integrator" which equals the OrderId.

Then i change the code to remove:

```
 public async Task<string> DeleteContractorAsync(int ContractorId)
        {
           var _contractor = await _context.ContractorData.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ContractorId == ContractorId);
            //var _subdata = await _context.OrderItems.Where(m => m.ContractorId).ToListAsync();
            var _orders = await _context.OrderData.Where(m => m.ContractorId == ContractorId).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var order in _orders)
            {
                var _orderItems = await _context.OrderItems.Where(m => m.OrderId == order.OrderId).ToListAsync();
                foreach(var item in _orderItems)
                {
                   _context.OrderItems.Remove(item);
                }

                var _productClass = await _context.ProductClass.Where(m => m.ProductIntegrator == order.OrderId).ToListAsync();
                foreach(var item in _productClass)
                {
                    _context.ProductClass.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            _context.ContractorData.Remove(_contractor);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return "Record removed";
        }
```

And it's work.